# Column Modifiers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this **Laravel Framework** and I am completely new to it.
However, I want to validate the form and I want email fields to be Null. I am getting this error message in my `laravel.log`

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null'

So, I have researched through **Laravel Documentation** and found the code that may gonna solve my issue.

```
Schema::table('your-table-name', function ($table) { 
$table->string('email', 50)->nullable()->change(); 
});
```

The problem is, I don't know the right place/file to place above code. Any help will be appreciated. Thankx :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration change_email_in_your_table --table=your_table
```

Then add this code to it and execute `php artisan migrate` command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Hi thanx for reply.. where and how to execute ``php artisan migrate`` command ?

Comment: Run terminal, go to Laravel project folder and then execute both `php artisan` commands there.

Comment: oh , it may sound Dumb, as I said I'm completely new to Laravel. How to run terminal ? Do I need separate Linux ?? Like Ubuntu ?

Comment: If you're using Windows, you should use cmd http://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8

Comment: I'm working on live site. So , if I run cmd on from desktop, will it work on live ?

Comment: For remote server, you want to use SSH client, which usually have built-in terminal. I prefer WinSCP which has terminal too https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_ssh_client_for_windows

Comment: hi ,  I created new migration , so I just need the reverting nullable query, I found only making nullable in the docs of Laravel. Can you guide me please ?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean. Best you can do is create new answer and describe everything in details. I will help you (or maybe some another guy will give you better answer).